# change Atom keybinding behavior depending on character near cursor

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, atom-editor, key-bindings

In the [Atom text editor](https://atom.io/), how can I make a keybinding take a different action depending on which character is immediately to the left of the cursor?

In particular:

- if the character immediately to the left of the cursor is a whitespace character, then I want the `tab` key to insert indentation.
- if the character immediately to the left of the cursor is **not** whitespace, then I want the `tab` key to open the autocomplete pane.

Answer (score 3):

you can extend this extension `https://github.com/atom/autocomplete-plus.git`.

first `git clone` the repo,
remove the extension from your atom if you had it,
then cd to your cloned directory, then install it using `apm link`

in the `https://github.com/atom/autocomplete-plus/blob/master/keymaps/autocomplete-plus.cson`
you can add the **tab** :

```
'atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-space': 'autocomplete-plus:activate',
  'tab': 'autocomplete-plus:activate',
```

and [here line 501](https://github.com/atom/autocomplete-plus/blob/d2a02b1fb7d228b2ea00065d6fe19f96f5731861/lib/autocomplete-manager.js#L501)
,before entering the while loop,
you can check if the last character is equal **space**

```
if(line[position.column - 1] == ' '){
    this.editor.indent()
}
```

and add **one level Indentation** .

Comment: This sounds very promising.  I will see if I can try this out sometime, thank you!